# Generating Bifurcation Animations

Tags: dynamical-systems, chaos-theory, bifurcation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hopf-bif.gif

Does anyone know how this animation was produced? I could make it by stitching together snapshots (what I'm doing) but this seems primitive, especially for how nice this animation looks. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I were to approach this problem, I would use a for-loop in Matlab to generate all of the frames, each of which I would automatically save as an image in memory, and which I would then "stitch" together into a video object, which I would export as an animation. This would make the process of doing it manually into a 30-second task, rather than an hour-long one. I'm also sure it could be done in Octave instead of Matlab, if you don't have access to a license.

Answer (score 0):

This is the Hopf Bifurcation in the Selkov model, lent from Mathematica Demonstartion [>>>here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HopfBifurcationInTheSelkovModel/)

See reference also directly [>>>here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_bifurcation#cite_note-Selkov_Model-8)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO : Convert sequence of pgm images into animated gif. 
You can use bash and ImageMagic like [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aQuadratic_Golden_Mean_Siegel_Disc_IIM_Animated.gif)